# Fix :Trying to get property of non-object in PHP

Tags: php

I had 4 lines of errors exactly the same as below:

> Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/sgclass/public_html/wp-content/themes/socialchef-child/includes/plugins/frontend-submit/frontend-submit.php
>   on line 1168

The code on line 1168 is:

```
$recipe_difficulties_str .= "{$recipe_difficulty->term_id}:{$recipe_difficulty->name},";
```

Is there any thing wrong?

The surround codes is below.

```
$this->form_fields[] = (object)array( 'type' => 'div', 'class' => 'third', 'is_closing' => false );     
            $taxonomies = array( 'recipe_difficulty2' ); 

            $recipe_difficulties = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
            $recipe_difficulties_str = ':' . __('Select difficulty 2', 'socialchef-child') . ',';
            //echo "dificulty2 value:";
            //var_dump( wp_get_post_terms( '1189', 'recipe_difficulty2' ) );
            foreach ($recipe_difficulties as $recipe_difficulty) {

                **$recipe_difficulties_str .= "{$recipe_difficulty->term_id}:{$recipe_difficulty->name},";**
            }

            $recipe_difficulties_str = rtrim($recipe_difficulties_str, ',');                
            $difficulty_field = array( 'type' => 'select', 'role' => 'internal', 'name' => 'recipe_difficulty2', 'id' => 'fes_recipe_difficulty2', 'description' => __( 'Select difficulty 2', 'socialchef-child' ), 'values' => $recipe_difficulties_str, 'class' => 'select' );
            if ($this->entry != null) {
                $difficulty_field['value'] = $this->get_entry_field_value('recipe_difficulty2');
            }
            $this->form_fields[] = (object)$difficulty_field;
            $this->form_fields[] = (object)array( 'type' => 'div', 'class' => '', 'is_closing' => true );
```

Comment: We need to see the full file in question.

Comment: Well, since the error is on line 1168, maybe not the *full* file, but enough lines around that area to get an idea of what's going on

Comment: Thanks. Had input the chuck of codes

Answer (score 0):

I think your result data was not an object but you were trying to retrieve it as an object so try to retrieve it as an array.

```
$recipe_difficulties_str .= "{$recipe_difficulty['term_id'] }:{$recipe_difficulty['name'] },";
```

**Note**: But you should print $recipe_difficulty before you going to retrieve data.